# Cannot parse a string from a JSON in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, openweathermap

I am trying to parse a JSON data from Openweathermap.org to read the current weather data for a specific city. I was successfully able to parse the temperature in Celcius and Fahrenheit formats. Nonetheless, I was unable to and allocate main in my code to a string variable named weatherCondition.

The structures included below:

```
    // MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let coord: Coord
    let weather: [WeatherElement]
    let base: String
    let main: Main
    let visibility: Int
    let wind: Wind
    let clouds: Clouds
    let dt: Int
    let sys: Sys
    let timezone, id: Int
    let name: String
    let cod: Int
}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct Clouds: Codable {
    let all: Int
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Codable {
    let lon, lat: Double
}

// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double?
    let pressure, humidity: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike
        case tempMin
        case tempMax
        case pressure, humidity
    }
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct Sys: Codable {
    let type, id: Int
    let country: String
    let sunrise, sunset: Int
}

// MARK: - WeatherElement
struct WeatherElement: Codable {
    let id: Int
    var main, icon: String
    var weatherDescription: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main
        case weatherDescription
        case icon
    }
    init(weatherDescription:String?, id: Int, main:String, icon:String) {
        self.weatherDescription = weatherDescription
        self.id = id
        self.main = main
        self.icon = icon
    }
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct Wind: Codable {
    let speed: Double
    let deg: Int?
}
```

The function that parses the weather is below: (weatherCondition is a public string.)

```
    func fetchWeather(urlinput: String, requestedTempUnit: Int){

    if let url = URL(string: urlinput) {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
    return
        }
    do {
    //here dataResponse received from a network request
    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                                   dataResponse, options: [])
    print(jsonResponse) //Response result
            do {
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                //Decode JSON Response Data
                let model = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: dataResponse)
                print(model)

                if let temp = model.main.temp {
                    if model.weather.first(where: {$0.main == self.Weathercondition}) != nil{

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if requestedTempUnit == 0 {
                            self.temperatureLabel.text = String(Int(temp)) + "°C"
                        }
                        if requestedTempUnit == 1 {
                            self.temperatureLabel.text = String(Int(temp)) + "°F"
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
            catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        }
        catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

How can I get the weatherDescription to be assigned to a string? Much appreciated for the help.

EDIT: JSON Response below:

```
Weather(coord: MapKitTest.Coord(lon: 27.09, lat: 38.46), weather: [MapKitTest.WeatherElement(id: 200, main: "Thunderstorm", icon: "11d", weatherDescription: nil)], base: "stations", main: MapKitTest.Main(temp: Optional(16.29), feelsLike: nil, tempMin: nil, tempMax: nil, pressure: 1011, humidity: 87), visibility: 10000, wind: MapKitTest.Wind(speed: 1.0, deg: nil), clouds: MapKitTest.Clouds(all: 75), dt: 1591013681, sys: MapKitTest.Sys(type: 1, id: 6979, country: "TR", sunrise: 1590979773, sunset: 1591032590), timezone: 10800, id: 311044, name: "İzmir", cod: 200)
```

Raw Response Below:

```
{
base = stations;
clouds =     {
    all = 75;
};
cod = 200;
coord =     {
    lat = "38.46";
    lon = "27.09";
};
dt = 1591013681;
id = 311044;
main =     {
    "feels_like" = "16.9";
    humidity = 87;
    pressure = 1011;
    temp = "16.29";
    "temp_max" = 17;
    "temp_min" = 16;
};
name = "\U0130zmir";
sys =     {
    country = TR;
    id = 6979;
    sunrise = 1590979773;
    sunset = 1591032590;
    type = 1;
};
timezone = 10800;
visibility = 10000;
weather =     (
            {
        description = "thunderstorm with light rain";
        icon = 11d;
        id = 200;
        main = Thunderstorm;
    }
);
wind =     {
    speed = 1;
};
```

}

Comment: Add the `JSON` response in your question.

Comment: @Frankenstein Added response.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you also add the raw JSON input?

Comment: @koen I cannot allocate the data which is read in the response as "main" which is Thunderstorms in this case, to be written to a variable.  JSON Response clearly has the data, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Maybe you could find a solution by doing a simple [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Openweathermap)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you implement your solution as a code?. Just to give u a context I want to use a switch statement to show a UIImage for each type of weather event

Comment: You misunderstood me, my solution is that _you_ do some research

Comment: Try to post valid `JSON` when you are doing so. Check if it's valid [here](https://jsonlint.com/).